# ICD10CM look up in python

Tags: python, icd

I am attempting to write an ICD10 CM program look up using an ICD text file saved on my computer. I need to input the icd 10 code and have the program print a text description of the code. However, when I ran my code, the description doesn’t match my code. I have tried writing my program using regular expressions.#ICD-10-CM PROGRAM LOOK UP

```
`pattern=""
 import re
 regex=re.compile(pattern)
 infile=open("icd10cm.txt", "r")
 #patient_icd10= input("Please enter the ICD-10 code or diagnosis: ")
 #pattern=patient_icd10
 code=[]
 description=[] 
 code_key_dict = {}
 desc_key_dict = {}
 infile.readline()
 for line in infile:
 line=line.strip()
 elements=line.split("\t")
 #elements[0]=elements[1]
 code=elements[0]
 description=elements[1]
 code=input("Please enter the ICD-10 code or diagnosis: ")
 print(description)
 for X in infile:
 description=code_key_dict.get(X)
 code=desc_key_dict.get(X)
 if re.search(patient_icd10, code):
 print(description)
 if re.search(patient_icd10,description):
 print(code)

infile.close()
```

Comment: please paste the code

Comment: import re
regexp=re.compile(pattern)
infile= open("icd10cm.txt", "r")
infile.readlines()
for line in infile:
    line= line.strip()
    elements= line. split("\t")
#for line in infile:
    line= line.strip()
    elements= line.split("\t")
    elements[0]=elements[1]
    code= elements[0]
    description= elements[1]
code= input("please enter your ICD-10-CM code number: ")
print(description)
description= input("please enter your ICD-10-CM description: ")
print(code)

Comment: #ICD-10-CM PROGRAM LOOK UP
pattern=""
import re
regexp=re.compile(pattern)
infile= open("icd10cm.txt", "r")
infile.readline()
for line in infile:
    line= line.strip()
    elements= line.split("\t")
    elements[0] = elements[1]
    code=elements[0]
    description=elements[1]
    code=input("please enter your ICD-10-CM code number: ")
    print(description)
    description=input("please enter your ICD-10-CM description: ")
    print(code)
infile.close

Comment: Edit your original post and then paste the code. and use the code sample button of the editor

Comment: You are using "add a comment' click 'edit' above the comments